# Is it possible to load zipped scripts via the script tag?

Tags: javascript

If I have a compressed script, for example stored at http://example.com/myScript.zip, is it possible to load it ditrectly from a script tag:

```
<script src="http://example.com/myScript.zip" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

[This old article](https://josephscott.org/archives/2006/07/compressed-javascript/) seems to say that it is possible, but I couldn't find any confirmation for modern browsers.

For the record, my motivation is that I sometimes work in environments that allow manipulation of zip extentions and not js extensions.

Comment: not exactly like that, but jszip can unzip zips that you load via ajax, and gzip will invisibly compress normal scripts over the wire. as far as actual script tags go, it must be plain js to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in that article in details - that behaviour was the bug in the browser.

You can use special javascripts code that will look the HTML document for such tags and load it by ajax. For example IronRuby does it like tis:

Load "engine" on the top of the page:

```
<script src="http://gestalt.ironruby.net/dlr-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then you can load ruby file in the zip

```
<script type="application/x-zip-compressed" src="lib.zip"></script>
```

http://ironruby.net/browser/docs.html

Answer (score 1):

No,by doing so the browser doesn't know how to fetch this result.

There is a way to compress the file so it would be smaller but the browser must support it,most common are `deflate` and `gzip` both supported by modern browsers this is a very known web master optimization and not just for scripts,the same thing goes for large html and style files.

I highly recommend to read Google [Make the Web Faster](https://developers.google.com/speed/) to understand how to optimize your website.

Comment: Thanks! Note that my question was about support for file extensions, not web optimization.